# Select column or null?

Tags: mysql, select, null

Can I select like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT idClient, idAcc,Description 
FROM client, account 
WHERE (account.idCliente = client.idCliente  
    OR account.idCliente is NULL )
```

Im getting trouble because it show to me duplicated results :x How can I do it ?

Thanks

EDIT:

RESULTS

```
idClient idAcc Description
    1   3   good    
    1   2   bad 
    1   3   bad
```

Note that im getting 2 diferent Descriptions for same idAcc

EDIT2:

I realy need that search by NULL or Not NULL.

Comment: Use [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: Don't use that join syntax... it's deprecated and very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an implicit join. Try using an explicit `JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Description 
FROM client
LEFT JOIN account ON account.idCliente = client.idCliente
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your query to use a LEFT JOIN so that you get all situations where there is a client.idCliente, but also those where the account.idCliente doesn't exist.

Like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Description
FROM client 
LEFT JOIN account ON client.idCliente = account.idCliente;
```